# about a good book - Vector Calculus[by Jerold E. Marsden, Anthony J. Tromba ]

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus

I start reading Vector Calculus by Jerold E. Marsden, Anthony J. Tromba and I want to know if there is a book with the answers of  the exercises. I like a lot this book, it seems to be made for a beginner but also for those who want to assimilate new knowledge.

Thanks :)

Comment: perhaps this will help http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126495/reference-for-multivariable-calculus/126499#126499

Comment: I learned from that book at one time as well, and have since taught from it (I like it as an intro to several variable calc). The answers and solutions to the odd-numbered problems are in the back of the book. What more would you want?

Comment: Dear @mixedmath: given that the *odd*-numbered problems are solved in the back of the book, can you really not guess what our friend Iuli wants? :-)

Comment: I know I sound like a weak wuss saying this-but I still fervently believe all textbooks should come with fully worked out solutions manuals. It's not enough to know the answer's wrong-you have to know WHY it's wrong. And the old response of,"Well,then students just look up all thier homework answers.",is garbage because students who really WANT to learn won't do that,thier pride won't let them. Students who want to cheat will cheat,with or without the manual. So I just don't buy that response.

Comment: [tag:reference-request] should not be used as a standalone tag; see [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/reference-request/info) and [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2498/the-meta-tags).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marsden and Tromba-from which I learned vector analysis under the eminent differential geometer Josef Dodziuk-indeed has a full solutions manual that's available from the publishers.  It's actually a pretty good book,if overpriced. You can get a better book for fraction of the price from Dover: *Vector Calculus* by  by Peter Baxandall and Hans Liebeck. It's a little more difficult then Marsden/Tromba and requires some linear algebra as prerequisite, but's beautifully written with many, many graphical examples,good exercises and distinguishes many of the finer points of calculus of several variables in 2 and 3 space. It's certainly worth the effort and you should get a copy as collateral reading.