# Suggestions for very challenging vector calculus problems

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I'm trying to find some inspiration for hard vector calculus problems that would be suitable for university physics students encountering the topic for the first time. Areas to cover are vector fields, multiple integration, line and surface integrals, and partial differential equations.

Any suggestions or sources are welcome.

Comment: Express the arc and surface elements, gradient, divergence, rotational and Laplacian in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185342) mentions these two books:

1. [Vector Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1429224045) by Jerold E. Marsden and Anthony J. Tromba
2. [Vector Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486466205) by Peter Baxandall and Hans Liebeck

You can also try to check out [Schaum's Outline of Vector Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071615458).

I also found the following [link](http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/ESSENTIAL%20CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/challenge/ess_cp_13_stu.pdf) which contains some challenging problems for vector calculus from Stewart.