# Books that develop interest in integration skills

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question, education

Which books develop interest in calculus? By calculus, I mean both the proof based elementary real analysis flavored questions, and also those highly calculation based integration/differential equation questions?

A bit of background so that this isn't too broad - I'm high school senior having background in  proof based math (due to olympiads) and I'm finding calculus (especially those long calculation based problems) really boring/uninteresting compared to number theory or combinatorics.

Comment: Which type of boring? Boring as in 'too easy', boring as in too tedious to write all that French $\epsilon$-$\delta$, or boring as in 'I don't understand this so I got bored'? Each case has a different type of book to look at.

Comment: @totoro  No I understand the proofs behind all the theorems used in high school calculus clearly. Just that I don't have a feeling "I gotta figure out this integral this look so damn interesting" but more like "meh so much manipulation grunt grunt"  when doing calculus problems, but the exact opposite is true say when I'm doing some number theory problems

Comment: You should go for Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics*. IMHO it is the best book for both theory and techniques of calculus and has large of challenging problems.

Comment: well, I dont like too much computations either, if not more generalized theory. It seems that happens the same to you. More over: combinatorics and number theory seems more closed to pure mathematics than integration or differential equations, what are closely related to real-world problems like in engineering or physics. If you dont like something its fine. However you can try to read some introductory books about these topics to see if something appeal to you.

Comment: You could have some fun with the [Putnams](http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/) Some of the problems are in calculus.

Comment: But well I gotta brush up my integration skills because it's needed in physics (and I'm interested in it)  and I'm lacking the motivation to work on the calculus problems due to lack of interest.

Comment: Maybe *Irresistible Integrals*.

Comment: Besides Hardy's book, which @Paramanand Singh recommended and which I also recommend you look at, three other well known books are Courant/John's book and Apostol's book and Spivak's book. See [Difficulty level of Courant's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79865/difficulty-level-of-courants-book) for discussions of all three, and also see the linked questions (and questions linked to those, etc.). For still other "honors level" calculus textbooks, see [Joseph Kitchen's Calculus (reference)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731087/joseph-kitchens-calculus-reference).