# Courant's "Introduction to Calculus and Analysis" vs "Differential and Integral Calculus"

Tags: calculus, analysis, book-recommendation

I'm considering buying Courant's books, but I have seen two series of textbooks written by him on calculus and analysis. What are the differences between these two? If I want to have a deeper and wider coverage, especially on analysis and proofs, which one should I buy?

Comment: Could you provide specific details about (or web page links to) the two series? Courant has written several books, and many have more than one edition and editions have more than one printing, so it's not clear which two series you're talking about. That said, you may want to look at the Mathematics Stack Exchange question [Difficulty level of Courant's book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79865)

Comment: I have went to the thread, but I don't find what I'm asking for. The links are too long to post here, but if you search the title on Amazon, you will see the books I'm talking about on top of the results with table of contents.

Comment: Regarding amazon links, it is helpful to note that https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Calculus-Analysis-Classics-Mathematics/dp/354065058X can be replaced with https://www.amazon.com/dp/354065058X (i.e. delete the title along with a back-slash), something I discovered a few years ago by experimenting. There's also "wordcat" (add this word to google searches), which is even more complete than amazon --- https://www.worldcat.org/title/introduction-to-calculus-and-analysis/oclc/635631 I've sometimes had to use worldcat links when a book I want to cite a bibliographic link to **(continued)**

Comment: doesn't seem to be at amazon, which happens from time to time. For example, [this book](https://www.worldcat.org/title/measure-and-integral-jaroslav-lukes-jan-maly/oclc/605233537) from my bookshelves doesn't seem to be at amazon.

Comment: So what are you even trying to say anyway? Do you have any opinion on his books, instead of talking about WorldCat or bibliography stuff or whatever?

Comment: *So what are you even trying to say anyway?* --- I was hoping that you would improve your question by being more explicit. Thus far no one has answered, and I suspect it's because no one wants to try and figure out exactly which books you're talking about. Note that saying *the books I'm talking about on top of the results* might have worked in 2002 or 2003, but not now, as search results are now all muddled with one's search history, one's location, etc. Incidentally, if you edit your question, it'll show up in the "most recent questions" queue. Right now it's likely to go unnoticed.