# Need a theoretical textbook for calculus, proof based

Tags: calculus, analysis, reference-request

The course descriptions is :
A theoretical course in calculus; emphasizing proofs and techniques. Trigonometric identities. Limits and continuity; least upper bounds, intermediate and extreme value theorems. Derivatives, mean value and inverse function theorems. Integrals; fundamental theorem; elementary transcendental functions. Techniques of integration. Taylor's theorem; sequences and series; uniform convergence and power series.

This course is using Spivak's calculus, but I'm also looking for another proof based book accompany with Spivak, thx

Comment: I have used four different books for analysis including Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds. My recommendation would be to use Kosmala's A Friendly Introduction to Analysis. It is almost purely epsilon-delta based, whereas Spivak will be using open balls.

Comment: Does it have plenty of exercise? How is its difficulty comparing to spivak?

Comment: Yes, there are many exercises and examples. I have never read Spivak's Calculus, only Calculus on Manifolds, so I can't compare. However, I do believe Spivak is an authority when it comes to calculus. I know manifolds wasn't an easy read.

Comment: One or more of the books listed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731087/joseph-kitchens-calculus-reference) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The Theory of The Calculus is called Mathematical Analysis ...Elementary Analysis for the R to R functions....so any of the very many books on Analysis should serve your purpose.

Comment: More advanced Analysis is usually approached "Topologically" Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds tries to do that...shame he does not know where to put apostrophies!

Answer (score 0):

You might try the standards:

1. Apostol - Calculus Vol I
2. Hardy - A Course of Pure Mathematics
3. Piskunov - Differential and Integral Calculus

You might also try Rosenlicht's "Introduction to Analysis". It's a cheap, awesome Dover book that presents basic analysis at a good level. Not exactly parallel to Spivak, but you might find the presentation enlightening paired with Spivak.