# Old books on calculus

Tags: calculus, soft-question, book-recommendation

I'd like to know if there are other old books of the same level of the classic and well-known books like Apostol, Courant, Spivak and Hardy.

Comment: what about Marsden?

Comment: archive.org has a lot of old books on many topics

Comment: Does anyone know Lipman Bers ? I didn't find enough information about it.

Comment: A newish book using old (but good) ideas: A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis, John Bell.

Comment: Edmund Landau wrote a revered book, Differential and Integral Calculus, published by AMS.

Comment: A list of such books appears in the accepted answer to [Joseph Kitchen's Calculus (reference)](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731087/joseph-kitchens-calculus-reference). By the way, there's another book I've been meaning to add to this list but had forgotten. I'll add it in a couple of hours or so, when I get the chance. Others are welcome to add such books, but please make sure they are really honors level texts and not just some book you happen to have and like.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro, Keisler is perfectly rigorous and in that sense also *honors*.

Comment: Is it true that Landau's book on differential and integral calculus does not have a single illustration?

Answer (score 4):

One of the best classics is [*Calculus Made Easy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_Made_Easy) by Silvanus Phillips Thompson. It is a book on infinitesimal calculus originally published in 1910.

Comment: I wouldn't classify this book as *of the same level of . . .* I would put Thompson's book in the same category as [**Commonsense of the Calculus**](http://www.worldcat.org/title/commonsense-of-the-calculus/oclc/1671551) by George William Brewster (1923) *AND* [**Elementary Illustrations of the Differential and Integral Calculus**](https://archive.org/details/elementaryillust00demouoft) by Augustus De Morgan (1899) *AND* [**Differential Calculus for Beginners**](https://archive.org/details/differentialcal01knoxgoog) by Alexander Knox (1884).

Comment: Well the OP did not explain what he means by level exactly. Are you interested in encouraging him to clarify? @DaveL.Renfro

Comment: I assumed from "*Apostol, Courant, Spivak and Hardy*" that very high level elementary calculus texts were being asked for, since these are the authors of the best known such books. (Best known here at least. Each of their texts is the main topic for quite a few math stackexchange questions.)

Comment: Hardy seems like a very old one that does not really fit into that scheme.

Comment: I agree, Hardy's book doesn't quite fit with the others, although it often gets grouped with the others in math stackexchange (and also in sci.math, before stackexchange came about).