# what uncommon book on calculus to read?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, online-resources

hellow,
Help me on what free pdf fundamental calculus book (preverably big font to read on mobile) to look at because all i have found here were unbearable to me. Best would be a consequent logical text first stated notation, conventions and definitions next in consequences without some chaos. If you know some uncommon books please provide a link to download.

Comment: Maybe [**Calculus. Analytic Geometry and Calculus, with Vectors**](https://o6ucs.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/mathmatics-1.pdf) by Ralph Palmer Agnew (1962).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thank you a lot, for me a good book would be step-by-step "guide", -you have definitions and then only clear consequence, in that mindset it is explicit that "problems" and numeric examples will look bad. i dont need intuition, i need clear rules and prefer less but good quality, anyway you were the only one who dare to responce here...

Comment: I suppose you could also look at the books in the answer to [Joseph Kitchen's Calculus (reference)](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/766183/13130), but given what you've said, they probably don't qualify. I don't think you'll find any calculus books that avoid problems and numerical examples (considered bad pedagogy, and also there is no market for such a book), but maybe there are some online lecture notes somewhere that qualify (instructor would present/provide problems and numerical examples in class lectures). However, I don't know of any such lecture notes, but I haven't searched either.

Comment: I think you are the only person, account, who can tell whether you would like any particular calculus book, so I'd advise you to just type something like "calculus textbook" into the internet and then examine what comes back at you.

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is sad that what have you wrote is true